# Drag object around a circle on mouse over - Adobe Animate/Create.js/Easel.js

Tags: javascript, adobe, createjs, easeljs

Using Adobe Animate HTML5 Canvas which employs Create.js/Easel.js.

I have the following code which drags an object around a circle.

Works Ok, but the object should only be moveable when the cursor is over the object; object being `streakRotatorKnob`.

```
var knob_X = 454;
var knob_Y = 175;
var radius = 80;

root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("pressmove",moveF.bind(this));

function moveF(e){ 
var rads = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY-knob_Y,stage.mouseX-knob_X);
e.currentTarget.x = knob_X + radius * Math.cos(rads);
e.currentTarget.y = knob_Y + radius * Math.sin(rads);
stage.update();
}
```

I have tried the following but it's not working at all with the `if statement`:

```
var knob_X = 454;
var knob_Y = 175;
var radius = 80;

root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("pressmove",moveF.bind(this));

function moveF(e){
    if(stage.mouseY == root.streakRotatorKnob.y && stage.mouseX == root.streakRotatorKnob.x){
var rads = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY-knob_Y,stage.mouseX-knob_X);
e.currentTarget.x = knob_X + radius * Math.cos(rads);
e.currentTarget.y = knob_Y + radius * Math.sin(rads);
stage.update();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Muhammed Maruf's answer below (the Adobe Animate version), the following works better by removing the line:

```
root.c.addEventListener("rollout", rollout);
```

So we just have:

```
stage.enableMouseOver();
var knob_X = 454;
var knob_Y = 169;
var radius = 90;
var root = this;


root.c.addEventListener("rollover", rollover);
//root.c.addEventListener("rollout", rollout);

function rollover(e)
{
    console.log("rollover")
    root.c.addEventListener("pressmove", moveF);
}
function rollout(e)
{
    console.log("rollout")
    root.c.removeEventListener("pressmove", moveF);
}
function moveF(e)
{
    var rads = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY - knob_Y, stage.mouseX - knob_X);
    e.currentTarget.x = knob_X + radius * Math.cos(rads);
    e.currentTarget.y = knob_Y + radius * Math.sin(rads);
    stage.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I edited the code. I think you meant that.

```
stage.enableMouseOver();
var knob_X = canvas.width/2;
var knob_Y = canvas.height/2;
var radius = 90;
var root = this;
root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("rollover", rollover);
root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("rollout", rollout);
function rollover(e)
{
    console.log("rollover")
    root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("pressmove", moveF);
}
function rollout(e)
{
    console.log("rollout")
    root.streakRotatorKnob.removeEventListener("pressmove", moveF);
}
function moveF(e)
{
    var rads = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY - knob_Y, stage.mouseX - knob_X);
    e.currentTarget.x = knob_X + radius * Math.cos(rads);
    e.currentTarget.y = knob_Y + radius * Math.sin(rads);
    stage.update();
}
```

```js
(function (cjs, an) {

var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
var lib={};var ss={};var img={};
lib.ssMetadata = [];


(lib.AnMovieClip = function(){
    this.actionFrames = [];
    this.ignorePause = false;
    this.gotoAndPlay = function(positionOrLabel){
        cjs.MovieClip.prototype.gotoAndPlay.call(this,positionOrLabel);
    }
    this.play = function(){
        cjs.MovieClip.prototype.play.call(this);
    }
    this.gotoAndStop = function(positionOrLabel){
        cjs.MovieClip.prototype.gotoAndStop.call(this,positionOrLabel);
    }
    this.stop = function(){
        cjs.MovieClip.prototype.stop.call(this);
    }
}).prototype = p = new cjs.MovieClip();
// symbols:
// helper functions:

function mc_symbol_clone() {
    var clone = this._cloneProps(new this.constructor(this.mode, this.startPosition, this.loop, this.reversed));
    clone.gotoAndStop(this.currentFrame);
    clone.paused = this.paused;
    clone.framerate = this.framerate;
    return clone;
}

function getMCSymbolPrototype(symbol, nominalBounds, frameBounds) {
    var prototype = cjs.extend(symbol, cjs.MovieClip);
    prototype.clone = mc_symbol_clone;
    prototype.nominalBounds = nominalBounds;
    prototype.frameBounds = frameBounds;
    return prototype;
    }


(lib.Sembol1 = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
    var props = new Object();
    props.mode = mode;
    props.startPosition = startPosition;
    props.labels = {};
    props.loop = loop;
    props.reversed = reversed;
    cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

    // Katman_1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.f("#000000").s().p("AhuBuQgtguAAhAQAAg/AtguQAvguA/AAQBBAAAtAuQAuAuAAA/QAABAguAuQgtAuhBAAQg/AAgvgug");

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.shape).wait(1));

    this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = getMCSymbolPrototype(lib.Sembol1, new cjs.Rectangle(-15.6,-15.6,31.2,31.2), null);


// stage content:
(lib.index = function(mode,startPosition,loop,reversed) {
if (loop == null) { loop = true; }
if (reversed == null) { reversed = false; }
    var props = new Object();
    props.mode = mode;
    props.startPosition = startPosition;
    props.labels = {};
    props.loop = loop;
    props.reversed = reversed;
    cjs.MovieClip.apply(this,[props]);

    this.actionFrames = [0];
    this.isSingleFrame = false;
    // timeline functions:
    this.frame_0 = function() {
        if(this.isSingleFrame) {
            return;
        }
        if(this.totalFrames == 1) {
            this.isSingleFrame = true;
        }
        stage.enableMouseOver();
        
        var knob_X = canvas.width/2;
        var knob_Y = canvas.height/2;
        var radius = 90;
        var root = this;
        
        
        root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("rollover", rollover);
        root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("rollout", rollout);
        
        function rollover(e)
        {
            console.log("rollover")
            root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("pressmove", moveF);
        }
        function rollout(e)
        {
            console.log("rollout")
            root.streakRotatorKnob.removeEventListener("pressmove", moveF);
        }
        
        function moveF(e)
        {
            var rads = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY - knob_Y, stage.mouseX - knob_X);
            e.currentTarget.x = knob_X + radius * Math.cos(rads);
            e.currentTarget.y = knob_Y + radius * Math.sin(rads);
            stage.update();
        }
    }

    // actions tween:
    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this).call(this.frame_0).wait(1));

    // Katman_1
    this.streakRotatorKnob = new lib.Sembol1();
    this.streakRotatorKnob.name = "streakRotatorKnob";
    this.streakRotatorKnob.setTransform(207.8,131.8);

    this.timeline.addTween(cjs.Tween.get(this.streakRotatorKnob).wait(1));

    this._renderFirstFrame();

}).prototype = p = new lib.AnMovieClip();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(467.2,316.2,-243.79999999999998,-168.79999999999998);
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    id: '214D9CE6C84FD84795816AF703BF00E4',
    width: 550,
    height: 400,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#CCCCCC",
    opacity: 1.00,
    manifest: [],
    preloads: []
};



// bootstrap callback support:

(lib.Stage = function(canvas) {
    createjs.Stage.call(this, canvas);
}).prototype = p = new createjs.Stage();

p.setAutoPlay = function(autoPlay) {
    this.tickEnabled = autoPlay;
}
p.play = function() { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndPlay(this.getTimelinePosition()) }
p.stop = function(ms) { if(ms) this.seek(ms); this.tickEnabled = false; }
p.seek = function(ms) { this.tickEnabled = true; this.getChildAt(0).gotoAndStop(lib.properties.fps * ms / 1000); }
p.getDuration = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).totalFrames / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

p.getTimelinePosition = function() { return this.getChildAt(0).currentFrame / lib.properties.fps * 1000; }

an.bootcompsLoaded = an.bootcompsLoaded || [];
if(!an.bootstrapListeners) {
    an.bootstrapListeners=[];
}

an.bootstrapCallback=function(fnCallback) {
    an.bootstrapListeners.push(fnCallback);
    if(an.bootcompsLoaded.length > 0) {
        for(var i=0; i<an.bootcompsLoaded.length; ++i) {
            fnCallback(an.bootcompsLoaded[i]);
        }
    }
};

an.compositions = an.compositions || {};
an.compositions['214D9CE6C84FD84795816AF703BF00E4'] = {
    getStage: function() { return exportRoot.stage; },
    getLibrary: function() { return lib; },
    getSpriteSheet: function() { return ss; },
    getImages: function() { return img; }
};

an.compositionLoaded = function(id) {
    an.bootcompsLoaded.push(id);
    for(var j=0; j<an.bootstrapListeners.length; j++) {
        an.bootstrapListeners[j](id);
    }
}

an.getComposition = function(id) {
    return an.compositions[id];
}


an.makeResponsive = function(isResp, respDim, isScale, scaleType, domContainers) {      
    var lastW, lastH, lastS=1;      
    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas);        
    resizeCanvas();     
    function resizeCanvas() {           
        var w = lib.properties.width, h = lib.properties.height;            
        var iw = window.innerWidth, ih=window.innerHeight;          
        var pRatio = window.devicePixelRatio || 1, xRatio=iw/w, yRatio=ih/h, sRatio=1;          
        if(isResp) {                
            if((respDim=='width'&&lastW==iw) || (respDim=='height'&&lastH==ih)) {                    
                sRatio = lastS;                
            }               
            else if(!isScale) {                 
                if(iw<w || ih<h)                        
                    sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }               
            else if(scaleType==1) {                 
                sRatio = Math.min(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }               
            else if(scaleType==2) {                 
                sRatio = Math.max(xRatio, yRatio);              
            }           
        }
        domContainers[0].width = w * pRatio * sRatio;           
        domContainers[0].height = h * pRatio * sRatio;
        domContainers.forEach(function(container) {             
            container.style.width = w * sRatio + 'px';              
            container.style.height = h * sRatio + 'px';         
        });
        stage.scaleX = pRatio*sRatio;           
        stage.scaleY = pRatio*sRatio;
        lastW = iw; lastH = ih; lastS = sRatio;            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = false;            
        stage.update();            
        stage.tickOnUpdate = true;      
    }
}
an.handleSoundStreamOnTick = function(event) {
    if(!event.paused){
        var stageChild = stage.getChildAt(0);
        if(!stageChild.paused || stageChild.ignorePause){
            stageChild.syncStreamSounds();
        }
    }
}
an.handleFilterCache = function(event) {
    if(!event.paused){
        var target = event.target;
        if(target){
            if(target.filterCacheList){
                for(var index = 0; index < target.filterCacheList.length ; index++){
                    var cacheInst = target.filterCacheList[index];
                    if((cacheInst.startFrame <= target.currentFrame) && (target.currentFrame <= cacheInst.endFrame)){
                        cacheInst.instance.cache(cacheInst.x, cacheInst.y, cacheInst.w, cacheInst.h);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


})(createjs = createjs||{}, AdobeAn = AdobeAn||{});
var createjs, AdobeAn;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
    NOTES:
    1. All tokens are represented by '$' sign in the template.
    2. You can write your code only wherever mentioned.
    3. All occurrences of existing tokens will be replaced by their appropriate values.
    4. Blank lines will be removed automatically.
    5. Remove unnecessary comments before creating your template.
-->
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="authoring-tool" content="Adobe_Animate_CC">
<title>index</title>
<!-- write your code here -->
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="index.js"></script>
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, anim_container, dom_overlay_container, fnStartAnimation;
function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    anim_container = document.getElementById("animation_container");
    dom_overlay_container = document.getElementById("dom_overlay_container");
    var comp=AdobeAn.getComposition("214D9CE6C84FD84795816AF703BF00E4");
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    handleComplete({},comp);
}
function handleComplete(evt,comp) {
    //This function is always called, irrespective of the content. You can use the variable "stage" after it is created in token create_stage.
    var lib=comp.getLibrary();
    var ss=comp.getSpriteSheet();
    exportRoot = new lib.index();
    stage = new lib.Stage(canvas);  
    //Registers the "tick" event listener.
    fnStartAnimation = function() {
        stage.addChild(exportRoot);
        createjs.Ticker.framerate = lib.properties.fps;
        createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
    }       
    //Code to support hidpi screens and responsive scaling.
    AdobeAn.makeResponsive(false,'both',false,1,[canvas,anim_container,dom_overlay_container]); 
    AdobeAn.compositionLoaded(lib.properties.id);
    fnStartAnimation();
}
</script>
<!-- write your code here -->
</head>
<body onload="init();" style="margin:0px;">
    <div id="animation_container" style="background-color:rgba(204, 204, 204, 1.00); width:550px; height:400px">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="550" height="400" style="position: absolute; display: block; background-color:rgba(204, 204, 204, 1.00);"></canvas>
        <div id="dom_overlay_container" style="pointer-events:none; overflow:hidden; width:550px; height:400px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; display: block;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's pretty good, but the problem as you probably saw is that the cursor can get away from the object, so you have to go and reposition the cursor over the object.  What I was hoping to get, and which may not be possible, is to replicate  drag functionality, which is what this tries to do, but not quite the same.  Any ideas?

Comment: See my update in my OP.  Change your answer for the Adobe Animate version after you test that solution of course.  The object moves responsively now that line is removed.  Moving the cursor away to stop the interaction doesn't appear to be a problem either.

Comment: Change the animate version and I will give you the answer.  Otherwise your answer is superb with the different frameworks in the answer!

Comment: Hi again.  Question.  The moveable object on the updated code in my OP (based on your answer) - what determines the starting position?  My object is set a specific spot, on on mouse move over that object, the object jumps to another position on the circle.  Any ideas?  Otherwise I will open another question and link here.

Answer (score 1):

I just saw what you wrote because of the time difference.
Let me answer your last comment as follows. In the example I posted, I averaged over the canvas. While you are giving the starting position, you need to enter the initial position information as if you were rotating it. I also solved a problem with Mac devices. The example should be:

```
stage.enableMouseOver();
var knob_X = canvas.width/2/stage.scaleX;
var knob_Y = canvas.height/2/stage.scaleY;
var radius = 90;
var root = this;

var rads = Math.atan2(1-knob_Y,1-knob_X);
root.streakRotatorKnob.x = knob_X + radius * Math.cos(rads);
root.streakRotatorKnob.y = knob_Y + radius * Math.sin(rads);


root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("rollover", rollover);
root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("rollout", rollout);
function rollover(e)
{
    console.log("rollover")
    root.streakRotatorKnob.addEventListener("pressmove", moveF);
}
function rollout(e)
{
    console.log("rollout")
    root.streakRotatorKnob.removeEventListener("pressmove", moveF);
}
function moveF(e)
{
    var rads = Math.atan2(stage.mouseY/stage.scaleY - knob_Y, stage.mouseX/stage.scaleX - knob_X);
    e.currentTarget.x = knob_X + radius * Math.cos(rads);
    e.currentTarget.y = knob_Y + radius * Math.sin(rads);
    stage.update();
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for this.  Now how would I change this to only half a circle (yeah specs have changed on me...)?  Question at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71568040/drag-object-around-a-half-circle-on-mouse-over-adobe-animate-html5-canvas